# Spelling correction like swift/swype

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, usability, spell-checking

I like typing and type with ten fingers since 20 years.

Sometimes I make mistakes or don't know the correct spelling of a word.

I like the swype-app in android phones. I am very fast although I use one finger, not ten.

I think the desktop typing speed could be improved a lot.

Is there a spelling correction which I can reach without using the right mouse button?

I would like to see the choices immediately on the screen and I want to replace the spelling mistake easily and fast.

Is there a tool on ubuntu which helps?

I use spelling correction in two places:

- Firefox textarea
- Thunderbird, writing mails.

I could change both apps if there are alternatives which provide better support for my use case.

**Update**

Wow, no answer, although this question has a bounty. It seems that there is no solution up to now. Just a hint: I would even buy an app which does this. I am not fixed on open source solutions here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a program but it is a simple trick I use quite often.  Firefox and Thunderbird will underline misspelled words with a red line.  Move the cursor under the misspelled word and press the [menu key](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=menu+key&iax=1&ia=images) on your keyboard.  This will bring up a context menu and suggested spellings will be listed at the top of this menu.  Use the arrow keys to select the correct spelling of the word.
[image: Screenshot with context menu open]

Pressing enter with the correct spelling highlighted will replace the misspelled word with the highlighted word.  This will also work in any program that has spell checking capabilities (LibreOffice, most web browsers)

It's not a program but there is no need for a mouse.

Comment: Exactly what I do too!  **;-)**